# Can't seem to call or create a specific method drawAll()?

Tags: java, methods

I am quite confused at the last step for my project can anyone explain this is the first part. Instructions haven't told me to create a drawAll()method so I assumed it was a graphics method but it doesn't appear on oracle? I'm new programmer help is appreciated. Thanks

```
After the sleep, call drawAll(g).  
The drawAll method will print the following on the screen in black at position x=10 and y = 15:  
Project 2 by YOURNAME.  
Replace YOURNAME with your full name.
```

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Project2 {
  public static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 300;
  public static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 300;
  public static final int SLEEP_TIME = 50;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics( );
    startGame(panel, g);
  }

  public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
      panel.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
      drawAll(g);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing your project, but there are a few options here:

    Are you allowed to use something like MAVEN? it is possible you are missing dependencies.

    Do you have access to specific libraries ? you may be missing some imports

    Are you sure you are not supposed to create a method called drawAll()? if there isn´t a method, and you can´t import a library, you won´t be able to call it. It is not part of the JDK.

Comment: I would say you have to write the method by yourself

Comment: Like CatsAndDogs stated, the assignment asks you to create a function called 'drawAll' that accepts a parameter (g). The drawAll method is to print "Project 2 by YOURNAME" to the screen in black at position x=10 and y = 15

Comment: Doesn't even look like you have defined the method or referenced an outside class at all, you just called a nonexistent `drawAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void drawAll(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("Project 2 by NAMEHERE", 1,15);
}

public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) 
{
    //start startGame
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
        panel.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        drawAll(g);
    }
} //end main game
```